# How can I obtain/build a wireless volume knob for Windows?

Tags: windows, hardware-rec, media-center, peripherals

I use my computer as a media center and simply love it.  It's an older box running XP and it works better than everything else I've tried turning into a media center (Windows 7, Vista, several Linux distros, etc).

The only thing I hate is having to walk to my audio amp to turn the volume up or down.  I can use the Windows volume slider or any keyboard with keys to control volume.  What I'd really love is to have a wireless knob which I can put anywhere when listening to music (e.g. kitchen) which controls the volume.  It seems so simple yet I can't find it anywhere.

Having controls for pausing and moving to next song would also be terrific.

[Griffin's Powermate](http://www.griffintechnology.com/products/powermateQD) could do the trick but I'd really want it to be wireless.

Do you know of something I can buy or build myself to serve this purpose?

Comment: Does your mobile phone have touchscreen? Try to find an app to do that. If you can program, just create an app to do that.

Answer (score 4):

How about a wireless mouse and the [Volumouse](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/volumouse.html) program from Nirsoft? With it you can set the scroll wheel to change volume when either no key is pressed, or when some media players are focused.

[image]

EDIT: Just noticed that this is similar to Moab's wireless mouse with AutoHotKey answer, just using a different application.

Answer (score 3):

See this article

http://www.instructables.com/id/Remote-Volume-Control-with-Wireless-Mouse/

EDIT:

xmouse is another option, it can intercept any mouse button and reassign volume up down to that button also

http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm

.
[image]

Comment: +1! I can't imagine using a computer now without using mouse for volume control.

Answer (score 2):

> I can use the Windows volume slider or any keyboard with keys to control volume.

There's your answer.  You want a wireless keyboard.  Get a bluetooth model for improved range.

You might also look into a [media center remote](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=media+center+remote&safe=active&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=68885883819658559&ei=n89iTYefFIetgQf005TXAg&sa=X&oi=product_catalog_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCoQ8wIwAg#) or a [logitech harmony](http://www.logitech.com/remotes?modulename=harmonycategorypage&moduleaction=exploreharmony).

Comment: +1 for suggesting a Media Centre-style remote control for remote controlling their Media Centre. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try that (for Linux and no knobs...) http://anyremote.sourceforge.net/index.html